# DependencyProperty for collection of buttons

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to give the user the opportunity to set a collection of buttons in my CustomControl.

I tried to solve this with ItemsControl like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type cc:MyCustomControl}}, Path=Buttons}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Command="{Binding Command}">
                <Image Source="{Binding MyImageSource}"/>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Buttons DependencyProperty:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Buttons", typeof(IList), typeof(TileGrid), new PropertyMetadata(default(IList)));

public IList Buttons
{
    get { return (IList) GetValue(ButtonsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ButtonsProperty, value); }
}
```

MyButton class:

```
public class MyButton: Button
{
    public ImageSource MyImageSource { get; set; }
}
```

And how I want to see it in CustomControl implementation:

```
<cc:MyCustomControl>
    <cc:MyCustomControl.Buttons>
        <cc:MyButton Command="{Binding SignDocumentsCommand}"
                     MyImageSource="pack://application:,,,/CommonResources;component/Images/Icons/pen.png"/>

        <cc:MyButton Command="{Binding DeleteDocumentsCommand}"
                     MyImageSource="pack://application:,,,/CommonResources;component/Images/Icons/remove.png"/>
    </cc:MyCustomControl.Buttons>
</cc:MyCustomControl>
```

But it's not working. In live visual tree i see only MyButtons inside ItemsControl. Is this a right approach? Or i need to solve it another way?

Comment: This will obviously not work because there are two Buttons for each item, one in the ItemTemplate, the other you pass in as list element. Is is supposed to only support MyButton, or do you want to be able to pass different Button types in the Buttons collection?

Comment: @Clemens, only MyButton

Comment: It's also unclear why there is a custom control with an ItemsControl at all. If you want to show a set of Buttons, why don't you simply use a regular Panel element, e.g. a StackPanel?

Comment: @Clemens I want to implement this control in one part of code with two buttons, another part with four, etc

Comment: Sure, but is there anything else in the control except the Buttons?

Comment: @Clemens, Yes. I removed it for my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type that you are using for the Button items in the ItemsControl should not be derived from Button. You may use something simple like shown below. It is also not necessary to declare the Buttons property as dependency property. A simple ObservableCollection is sufficient.

```
public class MyButtonItem : DependencyObject
{
    public static DependencyProperty CommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(Command), typeof(ICommand), typeof(MyButtonItem));

    public static DependencyProperty ImageSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(ImageSource), typeof(ImageSource), typeof(MyButtonItem));

    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public ImageSource ImageSource
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(ImageSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value); }
    }
}

public partial class MyCustomControl : UserControl
{
    public MyCustomControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<MyButtonItem> Buttons { get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<MyButtonItem>();
}
```

The controls XAML would just be what you already have:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Buttons,
                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Command="{Binding Command}">
                <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}"/>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

You would then add MyButtonItem objects to the Buttons collection:

```
<cc:MyCustomControl>
    <cc:MyCustomControl.Buttons>

        <cc:MyButtonItem
            Command="{Binding SignDocumentsCommand}"
            ImageSource="/CommonResources;component/Images/Icons/pen.png"/>

        <cc:MyButtonItem
            Command="{Binding DeleteDocumentsCommand}"
            ImageSource="/CommonResources;component/Images/Icons/remove.png"/>

    </cc:MyCustomControl.Buttons>
</cc:MyCustomControl>
```

Comment: That helped me except command.
I get an exception: "A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Command' property of type 'MyButton'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject." Making Command as DependencyProperty does not help.

Comment: Sorry, that won't work of course. There should be dependency properties. I have edited the answer.